# Is there a way to get multiple json key and values and store it in Json file in RobotFramework?

Tags: python, json, robotframework

I need to read the keys and values from json response and store it in json format using robot framework code.

I have tried robot framework code

```
  JSON RESPONSE:

       {
"data": {
"resources": {
"edges": [
 {
"node": {
    "tags": [],
   }
},
{          
  "node": {
   "tags": [
      {
        "name": "app",
        "value": "e2e"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cost",
         "value": "qwerty"
      }
  }
 },     {          
  "node": {
   "tags": [
      {
        "name": "app",
        "value": "e2e"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cost",
         "value": "qwerty"
      },
        {
        "name": "test",
         "value": "qwerty"
      }
  }
 }
 ]
 }
 }
 }
```

My robot code:

```
  ${tag_Count}= 3 ##Since there are 3 tags variable in response
  : FOR    ${item}    IN RANGE   0    ${tag_Count}
         \   ${resourceName}=    run keyword if     ${tag_Count} > 0   set variable    ${readName['name']}
         \   log to console  ${resourceName}-forloop
         \   ${resourceName_length}=  get length   ${resourceName}
         \   ${readkey}=     set variable   ${tag_variable[${item}]['name']}
         \   ${readvalue}=     set variable   ${tag_variable[${item}]['value']}

     set to dictionary  ${dict}    ${readkey}     ${readvalue}
     set suite variable   ${dict}
     ${req_json}    Json.Dumps    ${dict}
     Create File  response.json  ${req_json}
```

I required the response in this format in json file. How can i do it?

```
      {
        "name": "app",
        "value": "e2e"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cost",
         "value": "qwerty"
      },
     {
        "name": "app",
        "value": "e2e"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cost",
         "value": "qwerty"
      },
        {
        "name": "test",
         "value": "qwerty"
      }
```

I want to get the tag name and values alone and store in JSON file.
I am able to store only the last tag reponse in the json file.

Comment: My answer will be brief like your code, yes is there a way to do it. You only have to manage dicts

Comment: @Wonka, Sorry, I will past my try as well with dict. But the issue is it only stores the last tags response in json file. Can you guide me please?

Comment: @Wonka, Is there any way to do with set to dictionary or how to use append to list in python

Comment: Yes, with .append() but that code is not Python

Comment: can you provide an example in python?

Answer (score 0):

This is my json:

```
{
    "node": {
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "app",
                "value": "e2e"
            },
            {
                "name": "Cost",
                "value": "qwerty"
            },
            {
                "name": "test",
                "value": "qwerty"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my code (JSONPath in RFW):

```
$.node.tags..name
```

I hope this helps.